# Javascript ternary operation

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I saw the following in some code.  Is it necessary for the || false? If it is necessary, how so?

```
object.key = myData ? myData.value : false || false;
```

Comment: I have no idea why there would be a `|| false` there

Comment: I've never seen `||` in a ternary operation that isn't a part of the condition. Only format I know of is the standard `condition ? true : false`

Comment: The `|| false` also doesn't make any sense to me. Are you sure you didn't miss any brackets `(` and `)` around the code? For example if the original code was in form `object.key = (myData ? myData.value : false) || false;` then it would make some more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Quick review

`?` is the ternary operator

`:` delimits the output states of the ternary operator

`||` is usually the OR operator but in this case I think it was intended to be used as a coalesce operator

```
= myData ? myData.value : false
```

...will return the value from myData is it is not null; otherwise it returns false.

```
false || false
```

... will always return false.

```
= myData || false
```

...would return myData if it is not null, false otherwise.

If I had to guess, I'd think maybe originally the code was written like this:

```
= myData.value || false
```

...before they realized they needed a non-null object to get `value`.

Maybe they meant

```
= (myData ? myData.value : false) || false;
```

...which will return myData.value if it is non-null, false if myData or myData.value is null.

But if that's what you want I would write it

```
= myData ? myData.value || false : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes only sense, if a need for falsey values is `false`, instead of the falsey value.

**But that needs parenthesis to achieve.**

```js
var myData;
console.log(myData ? myData.value : false || false);   // false
console.log((myData ? myData.value : false) || false); // false

myData = {};
myData.value = undefined;
console.log(myData ? myData.value : false || false);   // undefined
console.log((myData ? myData.value : false) || false); // false

myData.value = 0;
console.log(myData ? myData.value : false || false);   // 0
console.log((myData ? myData.value : false) || false); // false

myData.value = '';
console.log(myData ? myData.value : false || false);   // ''
console.log((myData ? myData.value : false) || false); // false

myData.value = 'foo';
console.log(myData ? myData.value : false || false);   // foo
console.log((myData ? myData.value : false) || false); // foo

myData.value = true;
console.log(myData ? myData.value : false || false);   // true
console.log((myData ? myData.value : false) || false); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very sure the "false || false" is not needed here. However, the following expression makes more sense.

```
object.key = (myData ? myData.value : false) || false;
```

This compares a value(can be truthy or falsy) with a false using an 'or'. So, in cases where myData.value is not 'truthy', the object key is going to be set as 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), the logical or `||` is evaluated before the conditional (ternary) operator.  In all cases, this means that your expression evaluates to just:

```
object.key = myData ? myData.value : false;
```

Considerations about possible values for myData would be just noise now.